# Перенос колонок с использованием grid-сетки

Tags: html, css, css3

Возможно ли используя display: grid; сделать так чтобы количество колонок варьировалось не в зависимости от ширины, а зависело от высоты(высота задана фиксированным значением)
Пример кода: https://codepen.io/fess901/pen/gZEaKj

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.sub_unit-nav-block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  max-height: 300px;
  min-width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  background: #E1363B;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 25px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  font-family: 'robotoregular';
}

.unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub_unit-nav-block">
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Герметики</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Трубы</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Замки фурнитура</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Изоляция</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Герметики</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Трубы</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Замки фурнитура</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Изоляция</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Герметики</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Трубы</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Замки фурнитура</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="unit-nav_sub_unit-nav-block"><span class="text_unit-nav">Изоляция</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: тот самый случай когда можно совмещать `grid` и `flex`. Гриды используете для структуры, а вот для блока со ссылками уже флекс: `display: flex; flex-flow: column wrap; max-height: 300px;`

Comment: Сделайте пожалуйста работающий пример. Так как такое решение не работает, потому что контейнер не увеличивается в ширину, он просто не видит новых колонок, во всяком случае у меня в хроме это так работало.